# Changing table's border in VS forms code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am programming a web on VS , asp in C#.
I created a page and I made some objects "visible" property "False" and then when I click on a specific button they will be visible.
every object works except the table. I don't know how to disappear it in the codes. there is no property named visible. but I still can make the border =0 to disappear it.
the problem is I can not have access to that table in the code area. I gave a ID to that object , still there is not such a object in coding area. can any one help me that what should I do?
thnx

Comment: You need a lot of learning to do before you should start posting questions on stack overflow. Put a runat="server" attribute to the table and assign it an id then you should be able to access it in your code behind.

Comment: thanks man. it worked.
sorry I had to ask. if it shouldn't be here , admins please delete it. sorry for asking.